# How to remove manual line break

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-forms

I am getting the data from a form and writing in a google Document. It has fields like Name, Age, Address and so on. Address is of type paragraph text. My question is that while writing the data in a google Doc through a on-submit trigger script, how do I remove manual line breaks in the Address as input by the person filling the form. i.e. I want address to be a continuous string, without the breaks that the person filling the form may have put while typing his address.

ok here are more details.. the Address field in my form is called 'Address', i have a onformsubmit triggered script that reads all the data entered by the person in the form and puts in a google Doc App. 
i read the values typed in the form as :

```
    for(var field in e.namedValues) {
    message += field + ' :: ' + e.namedValues[field].toString().replace("\n",", ") + "\n";
}
```

But in my google doc, the lines for the value of Address sre still broken where the person filling the form has broken the lines. i want to eliminate these line breaks and substitute it with commas so the address is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

Change part of the line with the replace function to

```js
e.namedValues[field].toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ", ");
```

It works!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line breaks by taking the string that has the text from the paragraph, and passing it through `string.Replace("\n", "");` If that doesn't work, then you will need to provide more details.

Comment: @user1327454 You are adding the "\n" right at the end of the line, after calling remove. This might be part of the problem, but probably isn't. Another thought is that the Address field might be using html, in which case you need to replace "<br/>" or "<br />" or both. Could you post some dummy data from logging the contents of the `e.namValues[field].toString()` via `logger.log()`? [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_logger)

Comment: yumaikas, i use the "\n" to break each field to a new line. if i dont use the "\n", the values come continuously. Also, i put some some data and viewed thru Logger.log. The log file was exactly the way the address was entered by me in the form. i dont see any html tags.

Comment: It might be splitting the address field into separate named values based on the lines in the address field. If that is the case, then I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: yumaikas i did .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ", "); and it worked. no breaks in the address now. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can work with the range class:

```
function editRow(r){

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    var relevantRange = sheet.getRange(r, 21, 1, 1);

    artefactRange.setValue(relevantRange.getValue().replace(/(\n)/g, ', '));

}
```